# How do I display datalist in a 4*2 table layout in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am doing a queuing system. Now i need to display the queuing number in a 4 X 2 table like:

A1 has an earlier queue time.

```
A1     |     A5
A2     |     A6
A3     | (empty cell)
A4     | (empty cell)
```

The requirement:

- first 4 items will be listed vertically in the FIRST COLUMN, then the remaining 4 items will be listed in SECOND COLUMN.
- if only 6 items in the queue, leave the last 2 cells empty.

I have tried `RepeatDirection.Vertical` when using `Datalist`, but the number of rows cannot be set to 4.

Are there better ways to achieve the format?

Comment: Have you set RepeatColumns to 4? [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79k821wc(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I set it to 2. I want the result to be display in 4 rows x 2 columns @kennyzx

Comment: Set it as 4 and see if it works.  It is actually 4 columns in a row, and 2 rows in total. It is just it is vertically repeated so that it looks like a 4*2 table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `RepeatColumns` property to 4.

If `RepeatDirection` is `Vertical` (which is the default), the items are listed vertically in the first COLUMN until the number of items reaches `RepeatColumns`, then wrapped to the second COLUMN.

Think it as a 2 x 4 table that rotates 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you~ But I need to show the 4 x 2 table though there is no items. I want the items are listed vertically in the first COLUMN until it reaches 4 rows, then list the remaining items in the second COLUMN.

Comment: What is the output after setting the value? Could you provide the output by editing your question?

Comment: Setting to 4 would become 4 COLUMN  and 2 ROW

Comment: Oh... yes, can't believe what I see in my test, it is not working as it advertises in the document. Seems like this control is no longer supported now, can only find docs for VS2010/.NET 3.5.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you so much!